# Jquery: Disable button if there is no change in form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, input

**Goal:** disable button if there is no changes in form.

I already have a working code for this function actually, the only problem is I can't get it work if have a `input[type=file]` in my form. If I only change the file the button is still disabled.

Would you help me please?

Here's what I've done so far

```
$('#formEdit').each(function(){
  $(this).data('serialized', $(this).serialize());
}).on('change input', function(){
  $(this).find('input:submit').attr('disabled', $(this).serialize() == $(this).data('serialized'));
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you start out with the button disabled and only enable it when the form is complete enough for submitting?

Comment: That's what I did though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .serialize() method not work with **file** input types so you can use the **new FormData('form');**
Below is the working code for your use case :

```
  $('#formEdit').each(function() {
    var form_data = new FormData('form');
    $(this).data('serialized', form_data);
}).on('change input', function() {
    var form_data1 = new FormData('form');
    $(this).find('input:submit').attr('disabled', form_data1 == $(this).data('serialized'));
});
```

Please refer [jquery doc](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) to explore more on .serialize() method.

Comment: This works, though doesn't detect the changes. I think it only function like onkeyup. once the button is enabled it doesnt disable back it  only detects the action)

Answer (score 0):

achieving this would be very complex, you would have to use a hash of the previous uploaded file and if the user selects another file, you would have to upload that file to retrieve the hash to compare (using some edge-api to make the hash-calculation on client-side could be inconsistent). So you could determine (theoretically it would be guessing, because 2 different files have the very very small chance of having a hash collision), if the file is the same.

It would be much simpler (and less confusing for the user) to allow the upload of the same file again and simply exchange it on the server-side.

html

```
<form id="form">
    <input type="file" name="foo" />
    <input type="text" name="bar" />
    <button type="submit" id="btn">submit</button>
</form>
```

js

```
$(function(){
    $('#btn').attr('disabled', true);
    $('#form :input').on('change', function(){
        $('#btn').removeAttr('disabled');
    });
});
```